# curl from docker container return 'curl: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyutils.so.1'

Tags: docker

`curl` was installed by:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget.
```

When trying to execute the `curl` command from the container, I am getting:

> curl: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyutils.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to fix this error?

Comment: What is your base image? Please provide the whole Dockerfile to reproduce the error?

Comment: Means exactly what it says -- your curl package requires libraries you haven't installed (which is typically a bug in the packaging, unless someone has overridden package-installed files). This is more of a system administration question than a software development one, insofar as you could get the problem *outside* Docker by installing the same packages/files/etc in the same way on the same distro that your Docker base image represents.